# use xml for an ajax call

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I need help with this code because for some reason I don't get the data back
It is probably something that got mixed up, because I never used xml with an ajaxcall

Could someone check if they see something going wrong here

```
function updateGebruikersonline(){
    //voor het fade effect
    gebruikerslijst.hide();
    loading2.fadeIn(2000, function () {
        //stuur de post variabelen naar livetabs.php
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "/includes/livetabs.php", data: "actie=gebruikersonline",
            complete: function(xml){
                loading2.fadeOut(2000);
                gebruikerstoevoegen(xml);
            }
            ,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                if(textStatus == 'timeout') { 
                    berichtlijst.html(fout).fadeIn(2000);
                }else if (textStatus == 'error'){
                    berichtlijst.html(fout).fadeIn(2000);   
                } 
            }
        });//EINDE ajax
    });//EINDE callback loading
}
```

Edited: because I found the answer

I completely overlooked that I had to use this line in the php file, so that the browser will recognize it as xml.

```
 //php
    header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: Add this (your edit) as an answer and mark it as accepted, so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/) you can find full reference and I think you need to use **success** property and not complete, since it has different semantic.

```
function updateGebruikersonline(){
        //voor het fade effect
        gebruikerslijst.hide();
        loading2.fadeIn(2000, function () {
                //stuur de post variabelen naar livetabs.php
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST", url: "/includes/livetabs.php", data: "actie=gebruikersonline",
                        success: function(xml){
                                loading2.fadeOut(2000);
                                gebruikerstoevoegen(xml);
                        }
                        ,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                                if(textStatus == 'timeout') { 
                                        berichtlijst.html(fout).fadeIn(2000);
                                }else if (textStatus == 'error'){
                                        berichtlijst.html(fout).fadeIn(2000);   
                                } 
                        }
                });//EINDE ajax
        });//EINDE callback loading
```

If you do want to use complete, so you need to write:

```
                        complete: function(response){
                                loading2.fadeOut(2000);
                                gebruikerstoevoegen(response.responseXML);
```

Comment: no success yet. I know I used xml before with the post function, but know it will not work??
I get nothing back in the xml object

Comment: I still get nothing with complete either.Causing more errors also.
because it diddn't make it to my second debug alert.

Comment: try data: {actie : gebruikersonline}

Comment: Do you able to see xml result in firebug for instance?

Comment: I edited my question so it will include all.
The main thing going on, is that I keep getting an empty xml object back.

Comment: Look, you have better install firebug, since you need to check that you receive something at all from the server, because maybe the server side is not working.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Artem
I found the answer. I put it in the question above.